# php link from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am revisiting php and mySQL from a long time off.

```
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT Username FROM Entries ");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

<?php do {
//$name = $row_results['Username'];
//echo $name, "<br/>";
echo '<a href=\"$row_results['Username'],.php\">';
echo '$row_results['Username'],'s overview </a><br/>';
}

while ($row_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
```

What I am trying to do is echo out the link from the results the link is in the form username.php the username is stored in the database.

I have used single quotes and double quotes with escaped /" in but get different errors I know its going to be something as simple as a ; or " .
If you could be as kind to explane what is wrong abd if there is a better way to do this?

The query is correct and the commented out code also works on its own.

Thanks

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Sorry to sound think but am I allowed to use mysql_select_db?

Comment: The point is to not use `mysql_anything`, that includes `mysql_select_db`. The entire `mysql` extension is outdated. Refer to the first comment for better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parse variables through single quotes:

```
echo '<a href=\"$row_results['Username'],.php\">';
```

use

```
echo '<a href="'.$row_results['Username'].'">';
```

Comment: OP doesn't need to escape the `"` if they're encased in single quotes...`echo <a href="' . $row_results['Username'] . '">';`

Comment: This is what I have working with the help off all of you

      <?php do {
       echo '<a href='.$row_results['Username'].'.php>';
       echo $row_results['Username'].'\'s overview </a><br/>';
        }

       while ($row_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>

if i used 

         echo '<a href=\"'.$row_results['Username'].'.php\">';
         echo $row_results['Username'].'\'s overview </a><br/>';

the link was http://www.domain.com\"username.php"

Comment: @user1568373 change `echo '<a href=\"'.$row_results['Username'].'.php\">';` to `echo '<a href="'.$row_results['Username'].'.php">';` and you should be sweet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
echo '<a href="'.$row_results['Username'].'.php">';
echo $row_results['Username'].'\'s overview </a><br/>';
```

Comment: You don't need the empty string on the second line. `echo $row_results['Username']...` will work just fine.

Comment: ya right you can add space or other string there as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your errors :

1. Even though you are using `DISTINCT` in your SQL Query, there might be multiple entries, so you must use a while loop.
2. You had a comma in there (probably by typo).
3. You need to escaping the php variable.

So after doing the above, this is what it should be.

```
while ($row_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<a href="' .$row_results["Username"]. '.php">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT Username FROM Entries ");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

<?php do {
    //$name = $row_results['Username'];
    //echo $name, "<br/>";
    echo '<a href="'.$row_results['Username'].'php">';
    echo $row_results['Username'].'\'s overview </a><br/>';
}
while ($row_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the concatenation of your html string and the username is incorrect.

Currently, your string that you are writing to the page is

```
<a href=\"$row_results['Username'],.php\">
```

What you need to be doing is joining the html with the value coming out from the database.

This can be done like so:

```
echo '<a href=\"'.$row_results['Username'].'.php\">';
echo $row_results['Username'].'\'s overview </a><br/>';
```

Notice the '.' to concatenate two potions of the string, and the escapement of the apostrophe in the 's

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you got pretty mixed up with the " and ' there. You should really avoid using anything other than `'` - it will only bite you on the long run.

Also: You concatenate with `.`, not with `,`.

```
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query = sprintf('SELECT DISTINCT Username FROM Entries ');
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

do {
    $name = $row_results['Username'];
    echo $name.'<br/>';
    echo '<a href="'.$name.'.php">';
    echo $name.'\'s overview </a><br/>';
} while ($row_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
```

Comment: It will only bite you if you're not paying close attention to what you're doing. There's a reason both `'` and `"` are valid in PHP.

Comment: And what would that be? (Honestly interested) - I can't see any viable usecase for things like `echo "$var";`

Comment: `$arrCount = count($myArr); echo "There are $arrCount items in my array.";`

Comment: And how is that in any way better than the safe and consistent `'...'.$arrCount.' items'` way?

Comment: I didn't say it was better. You asked for a use case. Also, this isn't the forum for a debate.